# Parse, Join Tables, Pointers for simple task

Tags: ios, parse-platform

I am trying to have an object, which points toward multiple PFUsers under a certain Key. What is the best way to go about this? I read in the parse documentation that arrays are not the way to go, but it isn't really clear to me if I should use Join Tables or Pointers, or is this even a possible task. Can in 1 Object, can I Point to several, if not many PFUsers?

SOrry about this question if it seems easy, Just need to find an answer.

Answer (score 0):

I would store pointers for sure.

```
PFObject *yourObject = [PFObject objectWithClassName:@"SomeClass"];
yourObject[@"associated_users"] - @[[PFUser currentUser], someOtherUser, yetAnotherUser];
```

This has multiple benefits, mostly to do with querying.  You can query for the key to equal the current user:

```
PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"SomeClass"];
[query whereKey:@"associated_users" equalTo:[PFUser currentUser]];
```

This will fetch all objects that have the current user in the array.

You can also use `includeKey` to prefetch the users if you need their data:

```
[query includeKey:@"associated_users"]
```

Comment: I am trying to store a lot of information, like these objects could have a 100 people in them. do you think thats managable?

Comment: Yes, I think that's manageable.  The objects are just pointers which basically amounts to: `<PFUser : <#SomeId#>>`  Not much more than just storing a string.  If you have that many, I wouldn't use `includeKey` though because fetching the entire `PFUser` objects could be costly.  I'd wait to fetch them until you need them.